iOS in app payments are not allowed on some devices
Recently I've been trying to implement subscription-based service in my application using James Montemagno's InAppBilling Plugin. The problem I encountered is that I can purchase subscriptions using my sandbox Apple ID and everything is fine, but my testers get a popup with "In-app payments are not allowed" on launch.
We tried the conventional approach of checking if proper settings are enabled (i.e. In-app purchases in App Installations & Purchases) and everything was the same on their devices as on mine. At this point, I'm not even sure what other thing to check/configure. Have you encountered something like this or do you know what may be wrong?
